# Class with method, I don´t understand the class´s look

Tags: c++, class, struct

I am reading the "Learn C the Hard Way" book and found a code snippet there that looks like this (the below is my code, but the structure of the program is the same):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person {
private:
    string name;
    int age;
public:
Person(string name, int age) {;
        this->name = name;
        this->age = age;
    }


~Person() {
    }
};

// When whould I do like this?
class Person *Create_person(string name, int age) {
    class Person *person = new Person(name, age);
    return person;
};    

int main() {
    Person *person = Create_person("John", 30);
}
```

Look especially at

```
class Person *Create_person(string name, int age) {
        class Person *person = new Person(name, age);
        return person;
    };
```

What kind of function is that? Why would I call it like that and not just `Person *person = new Person`?
Is it a short form for

```
class Person {
public:
   Person *Create_person(string name, int age){
        Person *person = new Person(name, age);
        return person;
   }
}
```

?

Comment: Wait, "Learn C the hard way" teaches *C++* instead of C?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - yes, that's what makes it **hard**.

Comment: This seems like a bad book. Burn it!

Comment: At the very best, it appears obsolete.

Comment: looks like another function implement rather than a::b

Comment: It's a factory function. Not needed here, but sometimes a useful concept.

Comment: In theory a factory function can be a good idea. However a factory function returning a raw pointer instead of a smart pointer isn't exactly considered good c++ anymore. Considering that there isn't even a matching `Delete_person` (or whatever one wants to call it), meaning the caller has to know that the object is actually created with `new` I would suggest ignoring the whole function. If the rest of the book is similar, Luchian Grigore's suggestion to burn it seems reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing special about that function. `class Person` and `Person` are exactly the same type.

```
class Person *Create_person(string name, int age) {
    class Person *person = new Person(name, age);
    return person;
};
```

and

```
Person *Create_person(string name, int age) {
    Person *person = new Person(name, age);
    return person;
};
```

mean the same thing. The function seems pointless anyway, you can just call `new Person(name, age)` directly, as you figured already.

Answer (score 5):

`Create_person` is a global function that creates a `Person` object on the free store and returns the address of that object. In that regard, it's exactly like `new Person(whatever)` and, in this context, entirely redundant. There are contexts where this kind of function is handy, so this could be a gentle introduction to factory functions.

Comment: On the other hand, it could also be a Java hangover.

Answer (score 4):

The idiom of using a `CreatePerson` function, rather than doing `new`
directly, is called the factory method pattern.  It's fairly rare to see
it used for a class without virtual functions; it's usually used when
the calling code only sees an abstract base class, and knows nothing of
the actual type which may be `new`ed.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Person *Create_person(string name, int age) {
        class Person *person = new Person(name, age);
        return person;
    };
```

is a function in the global namespace that returns a pointer to a `Person` object. The `class` keyword is not needed here and can be omitted. Actually, it *should* be ommited. The reason why it is there is probably because it's "C-style".